# how to avoid data duplication request MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I create an online store, trying to implement the function "detailed view".The product is successfully displayed with the necessary attributes, but when viewing another product, the previous one is not deleted and accumulates in storage. Thus, the detailed product review form contains all the products that I added using the request.

This is class `Detail`

```
namespace App.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Detail 
    {
        private List<DetailLine> lineCollection = new List<DetailLine>();

        public void AddItem(Product product)
        {
            DetailLine line = lineCollection
                .Where(g => g.Product.ProductId == product.ProductId)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (line == null)
            {
                lineCollection.Add(new DetailLine
                {
                    Product = product
                });   
            }

        }
        public IEnumerable<DetailLine> Lines
        {
            get { return lineCollection; }
        }
    }
public class DetailLine
    {
        public Product Product { get; set; }
}
}
```

This is `DetailController`

```
namespace App.Web.Controllers
{
    public class DetailController : Controller
    {
        public ViewResult Index(string returnUrl)
        {
            return View(new DetailIndexViewModel
            {
                Detail = GetDetail(),
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl
            });
        }
        private IProductRepository repository;
        public DetailController(IProductRepository repo)
        {
            repository = repo;
        }
        public RedirectToRouteResult AddToDetail(int productId, string returnUrl)
        {
            Product product = repository.Products
                .FirstOrDefault(g => g.ProductId == productId);

            if (product != null  )
            {
                GetDetail().AddItem(product);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
        }



        public Detail GetDetail()
        {
            Detail detail = (Detail)Session["Detail"];
            if (detail == null)
            {
                detail = new Detail();
                Session["Detail"] = detail;
            }
            return detail;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the desired result:
[image: this is the desired result]

This is trouble result:
[image: this trouble result]

This Index View

```
@model App.Web.Models.DetailIndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Подробное описание товара";
}
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Название</th>
            <th class="text-left">Цена</th>
            <th class="text-left">Вес</th>
            <th class="text-left">Вкус</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var line in Model.Detail.Lines)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="text-left">@line.Product.Name</td>
                <td class="text-left">@line.Product.Price.ToString("# руб")</td>

                <td class="text-left">@line.Product.Mass</td>
                <td class="text-left">@line.Product.Taste</td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<tr>
    <th class="text-center" >Описание</th>
</tr>
@foreach (var line in Model.Detail.Lines)
{
<div class="container">
    @line.Product.Description

</div>
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the View for the front end?

Comment: It seems you keep adding items to the session without ever removing them. If you use MVC in the way it's intended you should never really need the session at all. I suggest you rethink your design

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET MVC, it's typically preferred to use a method other than `Session` to store data. `Session` is best used for [multi-screen wizards](https://uxplanet.org/wizard-design-pattern-8c86e14f2a38), where the results from the previous view/action are applicable to the next view/action.

I'll give you the 'fast' answer; and then will edit my answer later to provide the 'better' approach.

It looks like you're adding multiple product lines to the `Detail` class without removing the previous ones.

If it's a list, but you don't want to show more than one, why do you have it in a `List`?
Right now you `AddItem` without removing the item from `Session`.

To remove something from the `Session`; you would need to add this in the appropriate place:

```
var detail = (Detail)Session["Detail"];
detail.RemoveOlderItems(product);
Session["Detail"] = detail;
```

With `RemoveOlderItems` Looking like this:

```
public void RemoveOlderItems(Product product)
{
    List<DetailLine> lines = lineCollection
        .RemoveAll(g => g.Product.ProductId != product.ProductId);
    lineCollection = lines;    
}
```

It's hard to tell what you're trying to show (I think part of it is I'm having a hard time following what the screenshots of the view is showing since it's not in my native language; but I'm following as best as I can).  But I have a few further clarifying comments and questions:

What level of abstraction should the view be at?  Is a `Detail` filled with `ProductLines` ?  Are you wanting to show multiple product lines?  Based on the screenshots you showed, you really only want to show one.  If you only need one, then I'd remove the idea of the `List` altogether and have one `ProductLine` in the detail.

If you can further elaborate what the end result you're going for is, and why you have a `List` where it seems like you only want one result to show, that will help.

Comment: I made a "detailed view" based on the Add to cart feature, now I realized that this is not the right solution. The goal is to display a product with a large number of attributes in a different form. For example, the main form contains 3 product attributes: Name, Mass, Price. When in Detail list must be more attributes: description, taste, images etc..

Answer (score 0):

I solve solution adding to DetailController abandon session:

```
public Detail GetDetail()
        {
            Detail detail = (Detail)Session["Detail"];
            if (detail == null)
            {
                detail = new Detail();
                Session["Detail"] = detail;

            }
            else {
                Session.Abandon();
            }

            return detail;
        }
    }
}
```

However, how would it be better to resolve such a decision, avoiding the session?